# .IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, material-design

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

This is my code Showing error like this
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.colors.floatingactionbutton/com.colors.floatingactionbutton.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one theme of the AppCompact library like `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light` instead of `android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0):

[image]
In your Android Studio, click on the "theme button" and select the appCompat theme in the dialog.