# How to solve: IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: java, android

My app is failing to run in the emulator. The error cited is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I've read a number of similar questions, including:
[.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376815/illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant])

[ActionBarCompat: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063395/actionbarcompat-java-lang-illegalstateexception-you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcom])

But none of these have worked.

The code in the res>values>styles.xml file is:

```
<resources>

    <style name = "AppBaseTheme" parent = "TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name = "android:colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name = "android:colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name = "android:colorAccent">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>


    </style>



</resources>
```

The code in the src>main>AndroidManifest.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.hbpm1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application theme can not be `<style name = "AppBaseTheme" parent = "TextAppearance.AppCompat">`, because `TextAppearance` theme can't be used for Application theme at all. So, use any `Theme.AppCompat` as the default theme for your application. 
For this, I can give an example:

```
<style name = "AppBaseTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat">
```

or

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

etc.

Hope it will work